# MySQL statement that was working fine previously all of a sudden started being very slow. It includes alot of LEFT JOINs

Tags: mysql, sql

MySQL statement on a school system I have created some years back was working fine but now takes close to 30 seconds to pull what appears to me a simple statement but cannot figure out how to improve it. I am wondering if anyone can help me re-write this statement for a faster response. The statement is:

```
SELECT es.*,c.mainsubarea AS subject, b.name,b.email,GROUP_CONCAT(doc.document_file SEPARATOR "|") document_file 
    FROM usersubinfo es 
        LEFT JOIN userinfo b ON (es.uid=b.uid) 
        LEFT JOIN lkptsubjectarea c ON (es.mainsubjectarea=c.id) 
        LEFT JOIN lkptdeliverytime d ON (es.deliverytime = d.id) 
        LEFT JOIN documents doc ON (es.id = doc.order_id) 
    WHERE es.id AND es.is_active='Yes' 
    GROUP BY es.id 
    ORDER BY es.joindate 
    DESC LIMIT 0,25
```

[See screenshot from Explain statement on phpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUd5e.png)

Comment: `es.id` can be NULL or zero ???

Comment: @Akina es.id is auto-increment integer so is not and cannot be zero in the existing data

Comment: It can be due to lack of keys , data increase and more

Comment: *es.id is auto-increment integer so is not and cannot be zero in the existing data* If so then what's the meaning of `WHERE es.id AND es.is_active='Yes'`? taking into account the operators precedence it is `WHERE (es.id AND (es.is_active='Yes'))`.

Comment: If this is PK then limit to 25 rows in subquery then join and group by.

Comment: @Akina Thanks for pointing out - WHERE es.id is redundant but it does not make any difference to the speed of the statement.

Comment: @Akina "If this is PK then limit to 25 rows in subquery then join and group by." Can you help me visualize how you would achieve that - I am not sure what you mean by subquery limiting.

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM (SELECT * FROM usersubinfo WHERE is_active='Yes' ORDER BY joindate DESC LIMIT 0,25) es LEFT JOIN userinfo b ... ORDER BY es.joindate;`

Answer (score 2):

**Add Indexes:** These may help:

```
b:  INDEX(uid,  name, email)
doc:  INDEX(order_id,  document_file)
```

**Remove LEFT:**  Is there a reason for `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`?  I think not.  See if you get the same results without `LEFTs`.

**Remove bogus test:** Why `WHERE  es.id`?  If `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of `es`, that test will always be true.

**Improve GROUP+ORDER:** Change

```
    GROUP BY  es.id
    ORDER BY  es.joindate DESC
    LIMIT  0,25
```

-->

```
    GROUP BY  es.joindate,      es.id
    ORDER BY  es.joindate DESC, es.id DESC
    LIMIT  0,25
```

That avoids two passes over the data -- one for the GROUPing, and another for the ORDERing.  Meanwhile, I assume that my grouping and ordering is "just as good".

**Turn inside-out:** That brings up another issue, one I call "explode-implode".  That's where you Join together a lot of rows, only to get rid of most of them.  So...

Start by finding the 25 ids desired with as little effort as possible:

```
SELECT  id
    FROM usersubinfo
    WHERE is_active = 'Yes'
    GROUP BY  joindate,      id
    ORDER BY  joindate DESC, id DESC
    LIMIT  0,25
```

And include that as a 'derived' table in the rest:

```
SELECT  es.*, c.mainsubarea AS subject,
        b.name, b.email,
        GROUP_CONCAT(doc.document_file SEPARATOR "|") document_file
    FROM ( put the above Select here 
         )  AS ids
    JOIN  usersubinfo AS es  USING(id)
    JOIN  userinfo b  ON (es.uid=b.uid)
    JOIN  lkptsubjectarea c  ON (es.mainsubjectarea=c.id)
    JOIN  lkptdeliverytime d  ON (es.deliverytime = d.id)
    JOIN  documents doc  ON (es.id = doc.order_id)
    ORDER BY  joindate DESC, id DESC;  -- yes, repeat this
```

This is likely to be faster because the tables other than `usersubinfo` will be touched only 25 times.

(I think this will happen to avoid the "only_full_group_by" issue to which Parfait refers.)

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost, consider writing a valid ANSI SQL aggregate query with changes to your `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` clauses. Currently, your query includes only one column in `GROUP BY` but *all* columns from `usersubinfo` table with `SELECT es.*` in addition to other non-aggregated columns. You even order by a column not in `GROUP BY`.

Such a query runs against the SQL standard and will fail in most RDBMS's but allowable in MySQL due to its [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) mode turned off which dangerously allows:

> server is free to choose ***any*** value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are nondeterministic, which is probably not what you want

Since you have an aggregate function, `GROUP_CONCAT`, all other non-aggregated columns should be placed in `GROUP BY` clause. If you need to add columns in `SELECT` add it also to `GROUP BY`. Also, you may have a redundant `LEFT JOIN` which serves no purpose for other `JOIN`s or columns for `SELECT`.

```sql
SELECT es.id, 
       es.joindate,
       sa.mainsubarea AS subject,
       i.name,
       i.email,
       GROUP_CONCAT(doc.document_file SEPARATOR "|") document_file 
    FROM usersubinfo es 
        LEFT JOIN userinfo i ON (es.uid = i.uid) 
        LEFT JOIN lkptsubjectarea sa ON (es.mainsubjectarea = sa.id) 
        -- LEFT JOIN lkptdeliverytime dlv ON (es.deliverytime = dlv.id)  -- POSSIBLY REDUNDANT
        LEFT JOIN documents doc ON (es.id = doc.order_id) 
    WHERE es.id IS NOT NULL 
      AND es.is_active = 'Yes' 
    GROUP BY es.id,
             es.joindate,
             sa.mainsubarea,
             i.name,
             i.email,
    ORDER BY es.joindate DESC
    LIMIT 0 
    OFFSET 25
```

Additionally, by avoiding `SELECT *` you avoid bringing in unneeded even newer columns, allowing indexes to run effectively over large table scans, and avoid sending large amount of content over network. See [Why is SELECT * considered harmful?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3639861/1422451)

Comment: If `id` is the PK, won't that eliminate your comment about grouping?

Comment: Sure. But the other non-agg columns may not be functional dependent on `es.id`. Maybe not for efficiency but for readable/maintainable code, explicitly laying out `SELECT` columns would be ideal. But I defer to you, the mysql guru!

Comment: Good points....